# ASP.NET Web API with Linq2Couchbase dependancy injection

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, couchbase

I'm new to ASP.NET Web API projects and also new to Couchbase. I'm trying to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/Linq2Couchbase/blob/master/docs/bucket-context.md

Using a blank project and the code provided, I get the error: "No parameterless constructor defined for this object". I know that I need to "inject" the BucketContext in some way, but I don't know where to put that, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps following this tutorial will help you understand the Couchbase SDK in a bit more detail and let you understand the initialisation "challenge" you have.

http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/november/couchbase-dotnet-client-sdk-tutorial

In short, Couchbase Cluster is a "heavy" object and it's recommended to keep the object for the lifetime of the app. In WEB API that means that init should be done on app start. Depending on what version of ASP.NET you are using (ASP.NET 4.5 or ASP.NET vNEXT) init is done/recommended to be done different places.

ASP.NET 4.5 = global.asax
vNEXT = APP_START folder (look for other initialisations)

The above project/tutorial will explain step by step how to do the init.

When init is in place, linq2couchbase should work :)

Please let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, that really link really pointed me in the right direction. As you said, don't need to inject necessarily, I've instead set up a storage class as per the example. I can then just use `ClusterHelper.GetBucket().Query<dynamic>(query)` and pop that in a method, simple :)